# Unauthorized for docker stack deploy

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, corda

I have a project which I can run on macOS under Docker Desktop. But when I run the same under Linux/Ubuntu with microk8s, I get unauthorized for:

```
Removing pre-existing stack...
Unauthorized
Building docker images...
Sending build context to Docker daemon     65MB
Step 1/24 : FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8u172b11_jdk_unlimited
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for *.gresb.com, gresb.com, not registry-1.docker.io
Sending build context to Docker daemon     65MB
Step 1/24 : FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8u172b11_jdk_unlimited
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for *.gresb.com, gresb.com, not registry-1.docker.io
Sending build context to Docker daemon     65MB
Step 1/24 : FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8u172b11_jdk_unlimited
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for *.gresb.com, gresb.com, not registry-1.docker.io
Deploying stack...
Unauthorized
Docker ps:
Unauthorized
docker service logs -f CONTAINER
party-a SSH shell access
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@localhost -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -p 2221
party-b SSH shell access
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@localhost -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -p 2222
party-c SSH shell access
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@localhost -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -p 2223
```

The code is on github: https://github.com/henrikr3/corda-kubernetes-yo 
I am new to kubernetes, I tried to login to dockerhub but I am not even sure which endpoint it tries to authorize to.

Comment: Does your environment require a proxy setup that you're missing?  Are you in a particularly untrustworthy network environment?  When your host is trying to reach Docker Hub it seems to actually be getting another site.

Comment: No, just my own laptop, no proxies.

Comment: Hi, what ubuntu version are You using? Is this in a `VM` environment?

Comment: kubuntu 20.04 LTS, not in a VM

Comment: I have installed 18.0.4 LTS barebone to run docker run hello-world funny thing is I get different X509 entities per try

Comment: It's my provider again, I tried now a vpn connection and it was working fine. They even had issues with connections to Azure, which they "fixed", time to switch provider.

Comment: Glad You figured it out. Can You post an answer with Your solution so it is more accessible and viable to community?

Comment: Yes sure, I will wait for what the provider comes back with and add the finding then too.

Answer (score 1):

glad to see you were able to figure out that it was the network provider!

For anyone in the future who finds this there's a recent example of a similar setup for docker compose that makes clear how to setup a corda container cluster on github here: https://github.com/EricMcEvoyR3/corda-docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

My provider did not resolve the ticket, so I cannot tell what network setup they had that caused the issue. From previous experience with them having issues to use Azure their solution was to give me an IPv6 address. I assume they have an issue with their network layout. I switched the provider, rather pay more than waste time with issues like this.